# regular expression to match up to first instance of repeated character

Tags: r, regex, pcre

My example data:

```
l1
[1] "xmms-1.2.11-x86_64-5"     "xmms-1.2.11-x86_64-6"    
[3] "xmodmap-1.0.10-x86_64-1"  "xmodmap-1.0.9-x86_64-1"  
[5] "xmodmap3-1.0.10-x86_64-1" "xmodmap3-1.0.9-x86_64-1"
```

I am using R and would like a regular expression that will capture just the characters before the first dash. Such as

```
xmms
xmms
xmodmap
xmodmap
xmodmap3
xmodmap3
```

Since I am using R, the regex needs to be Perl compliant.

I thought I could do this with using a lookbehind on the dash, but I just get a match for the whole string. This is the pattern I tried:
`grepl("(?<=[a-z0-9])-",l1, perl=T)` , but it just matches the whole string. I think if I had the first dash as a capture group, I could maybe use the lookbehind, but I don't know how to build the regex with the lookbehind and the capture group.

I looked around at some other questions for possible answers and it seems maybe I need an non-greedy symbol? I tried `grepl("(?<=[a-z0-9])-/.+?(?=-)/",l1, perl=T)`, but that didn't work either.

I'm open to other suggestions on how to capture the first set of characters before the dash. I'm currently in base R, but I'm fine with using any packages, like stringr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Base R** An option is `sub` from `base R` to match the `-` followed by characters (`.*`) and then replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("-.*", "", l1)
#[1] "xmms"     "xmms"     "xmodmap"  "xmodmap"  "xmodmap3" "xmodmap3"
```

Or capture as a group

```
sub("(\\w+).*", "\\1", l1)
#[1] "xmms"     "xmms"     "xmodmap"  "xmodmap"  "xmodmap3" "xmodmap3"
```

Or with `regmatches/regexpr`

```
regmatches(l1, regexpr('\\w+', l1))
#[1] "xmms"     "xmms"     "xmodmap"  "xmodmap"  "xmodmap3" "xmodmap3"
```

or using `trimws`

```
trimws(l1,  "right", whitespace = "-.*")
#[1] "xmms"     "xmms"     "xmodmap"  "xmodmap"  "xmodmap3" "xmodmap3"
```

Or using `read.table`

```
read.table(text = l1, sep="-", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)$V1
#[1] "xmms"     "xmms"     "xmodmap"  "xmodmap"  "xmodmap3" "xmodmap3"
```

or with `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(l1, "-"), `[`, 1)
```

---

**2) stringr** Or with `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(l1, 1, sep="-")
```

Or with `str_remove`

```
str_remove(l1, "-.*")
#[1] "xmms"     "xmms"     "xmodmap"  "xmodmap"  "xmodmap3" "xmodmap3"
```

---

**3) stringi** Or with `stri_extract_first` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first(l1, regex = "\\w+")
#[1] "xmms"     "xmms"     "xmodmap"  "xmodmap"  "xmodmap3" "xmodmap3"
```

---

Note: `grep/grepl` is for detecting a pattern in the string.  For replacing/extracting substring, use `sub/regexpr/regmatches` in `base R`

#### data

```
l1 <- c("xmms-1.2.11-x86_64-5", "xmms-1.2.11-x86_64-6", "xmodmap-1.0.10-x86_64-1", 
"xmodmap-1.0.9-x86_64-1", "xmodmap3-1.0.10-x86_64-1", "xmodmap3-1.0.9-x86_64-1"
)
```

Comment: this answer is almost a mini encyclopedia of a specific regex problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could also extract till first occurrence of `"-"`. Using base R `sub`

```
sub("(.*?)-.*", "\\1", l)
#[1] "xmms"     "xmms"     "xmodmap"  "xmodmap"  "xmodmap3" "xmodmap3"
```

OR with `stringr::str_extract`

```
stringr::str_extract(l, "(.*?)(?=-)")
```

**data**

```
l <- c("xmms-1.2.11-x86_64-5","xmms-1.2.11-x86_64-6","xmodmap-1.0.10-x86_64-1",
  "xmodmap-1.0.9-x86_64-1","xmodmap3-1.0.10-x86_64-1" ,"xmodmap3-1.0.9-x86_64-1")
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I guess my question was too easy, since there were multiple good answers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest regex to match what you're after would be

```
^[^-]+
```

Match start of string (`^`) and at least one character (the `+`) that isn't a `-` (`[^-]`).

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/caMFLM/1).

If you need to capture it, add surrounding parentheses.

```
^([^-]+)
```